Troubleshooting code: Calculate the differences between mean-max and mean-median per peak in the same dataset, and print as standard deviation
I've spent 2 weeks writing code from scratch and improving it in various ways until this final problem.
My code is intended to calculate the two differences per peak (there are 2 peaks per dataset, and 6 datasets are analyzed at the same time), [abs. value of mean(x position) - max(x position)], and [abs. value of mean(x position) - median(x position)].
Once it does this, it must INDIVIDUALLY calculate the standard deviation for each, then print the two standard deviations for each peak (Peak 1 and Peak 2) per dataset.
My current state:
My code does not compute this for both peaks. It computes both differences per Peak 1 and Peak 2 correctly, per dataset. However, it only can convert one peak's differences into standard deviations.
Furthermore, I do not have much faith in the standard deviation protocol, itself- I have a suspicion that the peaks themselves are being computed together to create some average standard deviation which is not related to the differences mentioned above.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

# 1. User datasets:
x_data = np.array([25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105, 
110, 115, 120, 125, 130])
y_data50 = np.array([0, 0.50031, 4.00248, 9.50589, 13.50837, 15.0093, 16.00992, 17.01054, 
18.01116, 19.01178, 20.51271, 21.51333, 23.01426, 25.0155, 27.51705, 30.51891, 32.52015, 
33.270615, 33.770925, 33.770925, 34.02108, 34.271235]) 
y_data100 = np.array([0, 4.95405, 12.88053, 20.80701, 28.73349, 36.65997, 39.6324, 
42.109425, 44.58645, 47.55888, 50.035905, 52.51293, 55.48536, 59.4486, 63.41184, 68.36589, 
72.32913, 73.31994, 74.31075, 75.30156, 75.30156, 75.30156])
y_data150 = np.array([0, 2.96262, 8.88786, 35.55144, 51.84585, 57.77109, 62.21502, 65.17764, 
68.14026, 72.58419, 75.54681, 79.250085, 83.694015, 88.8786, 94.063185, 99.24777, 
107.394975, 115.54218, 119.98611, 122.94873, 124.43004, 124.43004])
y_data200 = np.array([0, 5.91543, 29.57715, 70.98516, 88.73145, 92.67507, 98.5905, 
102.53412, 108.44955, 112.39317, 118.3086, 126.19584, 132.11127, 139.99851, 151.82937, 
161.68842, 173.51928, 175.49109, 177.4629, 179.43471, 179.43471, 179.43471])
y_data250 = np.array([0, 12.31155, 39.39696, 83.71854, 105.87933, 115.72857, 120.65319, 
128.04012, 135.42705, 142.81398, 152.66322, 162.51246, 169.89939, 182.21094, 194.52249, 
206.83404, 219.14559, 221.6079, 224.07021, 226.53252, 226.53252, 226.53252])
y_data300 = np.array([0, 11.81124, 38.38653, 76.77306, 121.06521, 132.87645, 138.78207, 
147.6405, 153.54612, 159.45174, 168.31017, 180.12141, 188.97984, 203.74389, 218.50794, 
236.2248, 248.03604, 253.94166, 259.84728, 261.323685, 262.80009, 265.7529])


# 2a. Sigmoid function definition:
def compound_sigmoid(x, U1, x01, k1, U2, x02, k2):
    return U1 / (1 + np.exp(-k1 * (x - x01))) + U2 / (1 + np.exp(-k2 * (x - x02)))

# 2b. Derivative of sigmoid function:
def compound_sigmoid_derivative(x, U1, x01, k1, U2, x02, k2):
    sig1 = (U1 * k1 * np.exp(-k1 * (x - x01))) / ((1 + np.exp(-k1 * (x - x01))) ** 2)
    sig2 = (U2 * k2 * np.exp(-k2 * (x - x02))) / ((1 + np.exp(-k2 * (x - x02))) ** 2)
    return sig1 + sig2 

# 3. Sigmoid x-fit defined:  
x_fit = np.linspace(25, 130, 100) 

# 4. Initial guesses for calculating fitting parameters: 
#---------------------------------------------------------------
# (A-1.) [PERSONAL/EACH] >WORK DENSITY< Initial Guesses
p0_50 = [max(y_data50)/2, 38, 0.1, max(y_data50), 65, 0.1] 
p0_100 = [max(y_data100)/2, 38, 0.1, max(y_data100), 65, 0.1] 
p0_150 = [max(y_data150)/2, 38, 0.1, max(y_data150), 65, 0.1] 
p0_200 = [max(y_data200)/2, 38, 0.1, max(y_data200), 65, 0.1] 
p0_250 = [max(y_data250)/2, 38, 0.1, max(y_data250), 65, 0.1] 
p0_300 = [max(y_data300)/2, 38, 0.1, max(y_data300), 65, 0.1] 

# 5. Optimization parameters for ROI-specific calculation of the parameters: 
bounds = (0, [np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf])

# 6. Fitting the data according to the initial guesses and the compound sigmoid function: 
popt_50, _ = curve_fit(compound_sigmoid, x_data, y_data50, p0_50, bounds=bounds, maxfev = 
5000)
popt_100, _ = curve_fit(compound_sigmoid, x_data, y_data100, p0_100, bounds=bounds, maxfev = 
5000)
popt_150, _ = curve_fit(compound_sigmoid, x_data, y_data150, p0_150, bounds=bounds, maxfev = 
5000)
popt_200, _ = curve_fit(compound_sigmoid, x_data, y_data200, p0_200, bounds=bounds, maxfev = 
5000)
popt_250, _ = curve_fit(compound_sigmoid, x_data, y_data250, p0_250, bounds=bounds, maxfev = 
5000)
popt_300, _ = curve_fit(compound_sigmoid, x_data, y_data300, p0_300, bounds=bounds, maxfev = 
5000) 

# 7a. Calculation of the y-value compound sigmoid fit data per data set: 
y_fit50 = compound_sigmoid(x_fit, *popt_50)
y_fit100 = compound_sigmoid(x_fit, *popt_100)
y_fit150 = compound_sigmoid(x_fit, *popt_150)
y_fit200 = compound_sigmoid(x_fit, *popt_200)
y_fit250 = compound_sigmoid(x_fit, *popt_250)
y_fit300 = compound_sigmoid(x_fit, *popt_300)

# 7b. Calculation of the derivative series' y-values from the theoretical compound sigmoid: 
dy_dx_fit50 = compound_sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt_50)
dy_dx_fit100 = compound_sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt_100)
dy_dx_fit150 = compound_sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt_150)
dy_dx_fit200 = compound_sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt_200)
dy_dx_fit250 = compound_sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt_250)
dy_dx_fit300 = compound_sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt_300) 

# 8. Locating the peaks within the theoretical derivative plots (x-axis values): 
peaks50, _ = find_peaks(dy_dx_fit50)
peaks100, _ = find_peaks(dy_dx_fit100)  
peaks150, _ = find_peaks(dy_dx_fit150)
peaks200, _ = find_peaks(dy_dx_fit200)
peaks250, _ = find_peaks(dy_dx_fit250)
peaks300, _ = find_peaks(dy_dx_fit300)

# 9. Statistical parameter calculation functions according to peak distinction indices: 
def calculate_statistics(x, y):
    std = np.std(y)
    mean = np.mean(y)
    mean_location = np.sum(x * y) / np.sum(y) #-here, indices are based on distribution 
values. Only second half of sorted indices given.
    median_location = np.median(x[np.argsort(y)[len(y) // 2:]]) #-the median of the second 
half sorted is calculated. This is better for skewed distributions.
    return std, mean, mean_location, median_location

# 9a. Define a the maxima, distinguishing local and absolute. 
def find_maxima(x, y):
    peaks, _ = find_peaks(y)
    maxima = [(x[p], y[p]) for p in peaks]
    absolute_maximum = (x[np.argmax(y)], np.max(y))
    return maxima, absolute_maximum

# 9b. Calculation and printing of the statistical parameters' values according to bounds: 
def calculate_local_statistics(x, y, peak_indices, window_size = 5):
    statistics = []
    for peak in peak_indices:
        start = max(0, peak - window_size)
        end = min(len(x), peak + window_size + 1)
        x_local = x[start:end]
        y_local = y[start:end]
        std, mean, mean_location, median_location = calculate_statistics(x_local, y_local)

# 9d. Position of the maximum is found within localized metrics: 
        max_location = x_local[np.argmax(y_local)] 

# 9e. The distances [max. position - mean position] and [mean position - median position] 
are taken: 
        distance_max_to_mean = max_location - mean_location
        distance_mean_to_median = mean_location - median_location

        statistics.append((std, mean, mean_location, median_location, distance_max_to_mean, 
distance_mean_to_median))

    return statistics

#9f. Datasets referenced for individual parameters: 
datasets = [
    ('50m(f)', dy_dx_fit50),
    ('100m(f)', dy_dx_fit100),
    ('150m(f)', dy_dx_fit150),
    ('200m(f)', dy_dx_fit200),
    ('250m(f)', dy_dx_fit250),
    ('300m(f)', dy_dx_fit300)
]

# 10a. Local calculation of all statistics done for the listed datasets: 
for label, dy_dx_fit in datasets:
    maxima, absolute_maximum = find_maxima(x_fit, dy_dx_fit)
    peak_indices = [np.where(x_fit == m[0])[0][0] for m in maxima]
    local_stats = calculate_local_statistics(x_fit, dy_dx_fit, peak_indices)
    
# 10b. Standard deviations are computed for the distances found for the peak crest 
parameters: 
    distances_max_to_mean = [stat[4] for stat in local_stats]
    distances_mean_to_median = [stat[5] for stat in local_stats]

    std_max_to_mean = np.std(distances_max_to_mean)
    std_mean_to_median = np.std(distances_mean_to_median)

# 10c. Statistical parameters are printed 
    print(f"\nStatistics for {label}:") 
    for i, ((x_peak, y_peak), (std, mean, mean_location, median_location, 
distance_max_to_mean, distance_mean_to_median)) in enumerate(zip(maxima, local_stats)):
        print(f"  Peak {i+1}:")
        print(f"    Maximum Location: ({x_peak}, {y_peak})")
        print(f"    Std: {std:.4f}")
        print(f"    Mean: {mean:.4f}")
        print(f"    Mean Location: {mean_location:.4f}")
        print(f"    Median Location: {median_location:.4f}")
        print(f"    Distance from Max to Mean: {distance_max_to_mean:.4f}")
        print(f"    Distance from Mean to Median: {distance_mean_to_median:.4f}")
        print(f"  Std from Max to Mean: {std_max_to_mean:.4f}")
        print(f"  Std from Mean to Median: {std_mean_to_median:.4f}")

# 11. Plot data, logistic sigmoid function fit & the derivative: 

# 11a. Figures dimensions adjustment: 
plt.figure(figsize = (9, 10))
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.275)

# 11b. Datas' & Sigmoid Fits' series to be plotted in the 1st subplot: 
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1) 

plt.plot(x_data, y_data300, 'o', color = 'black', label = f'$m_{"w"}$ = $300m_{"f"}$' + ' 
Empirical') 
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit300, '-', color = 'black', label=f'$m_{"w"}$ = $300m_{"f"}$') # | 
$R^{"2"}$ Value = {r_squared300:.3f}') 
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit250, '-', color = 'purple', label=f'$m_{"w"}$ = $250m_{"f"}$') # | 
$R^{"2"}$ Value = {r_squared300:.3f}') 
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit200, '-', color = 'red', label=f'$m_{"w"}$ = $200m_{"f"}$') # | 
$R^{"2"}$ Value = {r_squared300:.3f}') 
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit150, '-', color = 'darkorange', label=f'$m_{"w"}$ = $150m_{"f"}$') # | 
$R^{"2"}$ Value = {r_squared300:.3f}') 
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit100, '-', color = 'gold', label=f'$m_{"w"}$ = $100m_{"f"}$') # | 
$R^{"2"}$ Value = {r_squared300:.3f}') 
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit50, '-', color = 'green', label=f'$m_{"w"}$ = $50m_{"f"}$') # | 
$R^{"2"}$ Value = {r_squared300:.3f}') 
plt.plot(x_data, y_data50, 'o', color = 'green', label = f'$m_{"w"}$ = $50m_{"f"}$' + ' 
Empirical') 

# 11c. Work Density Title [Stretched]: >USER SELECTION REQUIRED< 
plt.xlabel('Temperature (°C)', size = 11, y = 0.97) 
plt.xlim((25, 130)) 
plt.ylim((0, 275)) #- Suitable for presenting Stretched. 
plt.xticks(np.arange(25, 130, 15.0))
plt.ylabel('Work Density ' + '$\it{WD}$ ' + '(Nm/kg)', size = 11, x = 1.02)
plt.title('$\mathregular{[l_{i}}$ = $\mathregular{(1.5)L_{0}]}$ '+ 'Logistic Sigmoidal Fit 
to Work Density Data', size = 13, y = 1.02) 
plt.legend(prop = {"size": 8}) 
plt.grid(True) 
    
# 12a. Derivatives of the sigmoids' series to be plotted in the 2nd subplot: 
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2) 

plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fit300, '--', color = 'black', label = f'$m_{"w"}$ = $300m_{"f"}$') 
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fit250, '--', color = 'purple', label = f'$m_{"w"}$ = $250m_{"f"}$') 
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fit200, '--', color = 'red', label = f'$m_{"w"}$ = $200m_{"f"}$') 
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fit150, '--', color = 'darkorange', label = f'$m_{"w"}$ = 
$150m_{"f"}$') 
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fit100, '--', color = 'gold', label = f'$m_{"w"}$ = $100m_{"f"}$')
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fit50, '--', color = 'green', label = f'$m_{"w"}$ = $50m_{"f"}$') 

# 12b. Derivative Subplot Work Density Title: >USER SELECTION REQUIRED< 
plt.xlabel('Temperature (°C)', size = 11, y = 0.97) 
plt.xlim((25, 130)) 
plt.ylim((0, 10)) #- Suitable for presenting Stretched: USER SELECTION REQUIRED. 
#plt.ylim((0, 15)) #- Suitable for presenting Stretched-Annealed: USER SELECTION REQUIRED. 
plt.xticks(np.arange(25, 130, 15.0))
plt.ylabel('Rate of Change ' + '$\it{ΔWD/ΔT}$ ' + '(Nm/kg°C)', size = 11, x = 1.02) 
plt.legend(prop = {"size": 10}) 
plt.title('Work Density Rates (Derivatives of Characteristic Sigmoids)', size = 13, y = 
1.02) 
plt.grid(True)
   
plt.show()


Please read how to produce a [mre] and then edit the question accordingly. This will significantly increase the quality of answers.

@MichaelRuth Thank you Michael, I agree. For now, I have removed all the unnecessary 'libraries' that were commented in. It is much easier to follow, now.

it's not very clear what you are asking, a peak is a single datapoint, whereas the mean, median, and std are values that are calculated using many points. How do you want to calculate mean, median and std for a peak. Or do you want to collect all peaks and then calculate these values? please shorten your code, currently it is very long. No need for the plotting section or doing the calculations for 50-300. Give us a minimal example as Michael Ruth said, something to help us write a prototype for you.

Could you explain a bit more in details what computation you aim to perform once you have the location of derivative peaks. This is not clear in your OP what you want to achieve. When you says you want standard deviation of peak, do you mean you assume they are Gaussian and want to get this parameter? A manual sketch of the situation if fine too.

Additionally as you stated your problem, both peak should be scaled logistic distribution which as symmetric (mean = median = mode).

You can easily compute all basic information you need in a single pass. That will make your code easier to understand and invariant wrt number of datasets.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize, stats, signal

We group all your dataset into a single array:
y_data = np.stack([
  y_data50, y_data100, y_data150, y_data200, y_data250, y_data300
]).T

Then your final model (derivative) is the sum of two scaled logistic distributions:
def peak(x, A, loc, scale):
    law = stats.logistic(loc=loc, scale=scale)
    return A * law.pdf(x) / law.pdf(loc)

def model(x, A0, loc0, scale0, A1, loc1, scale1):
    return peak(x, A0, loc0, scale0) + peak(x, A1, loc1, scale1)

Now we can regress your model against your dataset, identify peaks and regress them in a single sequence:
xlin = np.linspace(x_data.min(), x_data.max(), 1000)

results = []
for y in y_data.T:
    
    p0 = [np.max(y) / 2., 38., 0.1, np.max(y), 65., 0.1]
    popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(compound_sigmoid, x_data, y, p0=p0, bounds=(0., np.inf))
    
    dylin = compound_sigmoid_derivative(xlin, *popt)
    peaks, _ = signal.find_peaks(dylin)
    
    p02 = [1., xlin[peaks[0]], 1., 1., xlin[peaks[1]], 1.]
    popt2, pcov2 = optimize.curve_fit(model, xlin, dylin, p0=p02)
    
    results.append({
        "x": x_data,
        "y": y,
        "popt": popt,
        "pcov": pcov,
        "xlin": xlin,
        "ylin": compound_sigmoid(xlin, *popt),
        "dylin": dylin,
        "peaks": peaks,
        "xpeak": xlin[peaks],
        "ypeak": dylin[peaks],
        "popt2": popt2,
        "pcov2": pcov2,
        "fit": model(xlin, *popt2)
    })

We can visually confirm fit are reasonable (fitness is good):

And indeed, because of the nature of your model, we can regress a sum of scaled logistic distributions from the derivative of your fitted datasets:

In this case fitness is perfect and regressed parameters are available in results[i]["popt2"] for each i-th dataset.
Now it's up to you to update your post with a clearer description of what you want exactly compute if logistic loc and scale for each peak is not what you are looking for.
